# Is it possible for me to read iOS source code for classes such as CFWriteStreamRef and NSOutputStream?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I would like to review for myself the error handling and buffering that Apple has implemented on top of their implementation of sockets.

Is it possible for me to read that code?

Thank you

Comment: No, Apple doesn't provide their source code.

Comment: @rmaddy It seems like they provide some of their source code here: http://www.opensource.apple.com

Comment: Yes, for some things they do. But in general, most of their code isn't open source.